# Pandas, Excel-Import and MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am new to pandas and currently trying to make some analysis of Excel-data in the following Schema:

[image]

**My goal is** a visualisation with the index-labels `XYZ`, `CDE`, `EFG`, `HU` on the x-axis and the corresponing `Perc`-values of `Yes`, `ProbYes`, `X`, `ProbNo`, `No` stacked on the y-axis.

Currently I'm parsing the Excel-data into a panda `DataFrame` via the code:

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'x1.xlsx'
x = pd.ExcelFile(path)
sheets = x.sheet_names
table = x.parse(sheets[0], header=2) # take line 2 as column-names
```

The generated `MultiIndex` of `table` seems to be fine:

```
>>> table.index 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Individual', u'Summary'], [u'ABC', u'CDE', u'EFG', u'HIJ'], [u'Abs', u'Perc']], labels=[[0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1], [0, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1, -1, -1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

However, it's neither possible to access a specific row:

```
>>> table.ix[('Individual', 'CDE')]
KeyError: 'Key length (2) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'
```

... nor is it possible to access or filter / remove a column containing the row indices

```
>>> table.index.names
FrozenList([None, None, None])
```

i.e. the indices have no names and so I guess I cannot access them?

I tried to simplify the data structure via the alternative parse:

```
>>> table2 = x.parse(sheets[0], header=2, skiprows=2, parse_cols='B,:I')
```

that, however, didnt really help.

**Edit**:

It doenst help to `sort`:

```
>>> table.sort(inplace=True)
>>> table[:4]
```

yields:

[image]

and with that table I cannot do my analysis...

Comment: can you convert to a CSV? it's pretty straight forward with CSV files: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#reading-columns-with-a-multiindex ...or perhaps a similar function call will work in Excel.

Comment: Ok, I'll try... So you think it's a Problem with the Excel-import? Although the MultiIndex seems to be perfect - besides the fact that the `lexsort_depth` of the index is `0`...

Comment: I don't think the Excel parser is as powerful as the CSV parser. The link I posted shows the format of the CSV you need and how to get a MultiIndex in the columns directly from a call to `pandas.read_csv`

Comment: pandas.read_excel has more or less the same functionality as read_csv (some keywords are not listed in the docs for read_excel yet keywords arguments from read_csv can still be used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think after doing

```
table.sort(inplace=True)
```

you may be able to access

```
table.ix[('Individual', 'CDE')]
```

EDIT:

I know why -- Your excel file has merged cells such `A4:A11`. When you load it into pandas DataFrame, the index `Individual` is only in `A4` while indices in `A5:A11` are all `nan`

One work-around I can think of is:

```
table =table.reset_index().fillna(method='ffill').set_index(['level_0','level_1','level_2'])
#reset_index() automatically gives column names level_?
```

Then you are good to go:

```
table.ix[('Individual','CDE')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, a `sort` doesnt seem to make sense here. After the sort, the table contains all the `Perc`-Values in the upper part, without the values of the second index.